# how to make background-color green when link is open in iframe?

Tags: html, css

[i write the code of this image.i want to make background-color green when link is open in iframe.ifreame i present below the navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxRef.png)

can i do this using css i tried to use :acvtive selector but that is not working with iframe. is there another way to make it look like this?

```
     <style>
      a.lis:active {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
      }

      a.lis {
          color: white;
          font-size: 19px;
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: 10px;
          text-decoration: none;
          margin-bottom: 0px;
          float: left;
          disply: inline-block;
          height: 30px;
          background-color: #5F5F5F;
          padding: 14px 10px 10px 5px;
      }

      a.lis:hover {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
      }
  </style>
  <ul class="list">
      <li class="icolist">
          <img class="icohome" src="home.png" width="25px" height="25px" target="ifrm">
      </li>
      <li><a target="ifrm">Best places</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="lis" href="http://localhost/signup.php" target="ifrm">Hotels</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="lis" href="#" target="ifrm">Videos</a>
      </li>
      <li><a class="lis" href="#" target="ifrm">Best routes</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Can I see your iframe code?

Comment: sure <iframe src="http://localhost/home.php" width="100%" height="1000px" name="ifrm"></iframe>

Comment: I tested your code and it seems to work alright. Unless your problem is not the color?

Comment: You may have other css code that may be overriding it

Comment: i want to solve the color problem.when link is opened in ifram then the link background color become green.i want to do this

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem i used :focus selector for links and it is working well.thanx to all who give answers